# expo-sharing wont save to files IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, expo-file-system

I am using Expo file system and expo sharing to download PDF files from my express server. I am encountering a weird issue where on Android it works as expected, but on IOS, when i choose the Save to files option, the file does not save. The strange part is if I select another option from the share menu, such as send via text message, the file is sent properly. Any ideas?

```
const save = async (uri, filename, mimetype) => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            const permissions = await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync()
            if (permissions.granted) {
                const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 })
                await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.createFileAsync(permissions.directoryUri, filename, mimetype)
                    .then(async (uri) => {
                        await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(uri, base64, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 })
                    })
                    .catch((e) => console.log(e))
            } else {
                shareAsync(uri)
            }
        } else {
            await shareAsync(uri, { mimeType: mimetype, UTI: mimetype })
        }
    }

    const downloadFile = async () => {
        try {
            setFileLoading(true)
            const config: any = { headers: { responseType: 'application/pdf' } }

            const fileName = `myfile.pdf`
            const result = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
                'apiPath',
                FileSystem.documentDirectory + `/${fileName}/`
            )
            save(result.uri, fileName, 'application/pdf')
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        } finally {
            setFileLoading(null)
        }
    }
```

I dont know what else to try, but as I said before, downloading the file on android works as expected, and IOS allows me to interact with the files in different ways other than downloading.